# blackberry socket / http connection seems dropping while sending sms

Tags: sockets, tcp, blackberry, sms, cellular-network

We've encountered the following issue in our Blackberry app:

some users are unable to connect to our server (neither through TCP socket nor HTTP), when they are using 2G/Edge network. 
However, they are able to connect successfully while using 3G/WiFi.

We suspect the 2G/Edge network failure is because our app send SMS before we start network (which is essential to our work flow here), and somehow 2G/Edge network is interfered/disrupted by the SMS sending thing. But we cannot reproduce the problem at our side and our clients are far far away from us.

I wonder has anyone experienced similar problem before?

Here is how we open the socket connection:

```java
private static int[] preferredTransportTypes = {
        TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI,
        TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2,
        TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B,
        TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS, };//

public SocketConnection getConnection() throws IOException {
    String serverUrl = "socket://" + Adaptor.getInstance().monetUrl + ":"
            + Adaptor.getInstance().monetPort;


    ConnectionFactory connFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    connFactory.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
    connFactory.setTimeoutSupported(true);
    connFactory.setPreferredTransportTypes(preferredTransportTypes);
    ConnectionDescriptor cd = connFactory.getConnection(serverUrl);

    SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) cd.getConnection();

    return sc;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you send an SMS and then wait for some time?  Can you then make an IP connection over GPRS?  If it is that, then it sounds like a device bug - have you raised an issue with RIM?

Comment: Thanks for replying friend. We actually waited after sending the sms. No I haven't raise this issue with RIM, because not all user would fail. I suspect it is still software issue, could it be the way I send sms in blackberry? is there more than one ways?

Comment: I am not aware of a reliable way to send SMS via the Blackberry, from a computer.  If someone else knows how to do this, I would also be interested to know.  Do raise it with RIM, even though it doesn't happen every time - they will be able to say if it is a known limitation.

Comment: I think you are right!